# Updating an Excel Visual Basic Spreadsheet Generator Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following macro to split a spreadsheet and save the splits into individual files:

```
    Sub DistributeRows()
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngCrit As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

    LastRow = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wsData.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    Set rngCrit = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    While rngCrit.Value <> ""
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
        wsData.Range("A1:AB" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rngCrit.Offset(-1).Resize(2), CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
        wsNew.Name = rngCrit
        wsNew.Copy
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        wbNew.SaveAs "C:\Users\nahansen\Desktop\Tornstrom Reports\MMGS" & "\" & wsNew.Range("B2") & "\" & rngCrit & " - " & "December 2018"
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wsNew.Delete
        rngCrit.EntireRow.Delete
        Set rngCrit = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    Wend

    wsCrit.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I want to add some code to the while loop that will format the data as a table, such as Medium 15. I know the code has to go in the loop before the save statement, but I haven't been able to figure it out, as I am really new to VBA and I am modifying a macro someone else made and we've just been using by rote. The goal is to make it so we don't have to manually open hundreds of excel files and click on the format as table button.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
wsNew.Name = rngCrit
wsNew.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, wsNew.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
wsNew.ListObjects(1).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
'etc etc
```